# Get Variable Value outside of Object Property

Tags: javascript, angular, object

I'm still a newbie to angular and js but I'm trying to setup a interactive world map where you click one country and get some values.
I'm using jsvectormap and angular. Jsvectormap provides the onRegionClick function. Within that function i set the country variable to the clicked country which works fine. but i cant access this value outside of the object property.

See the code in this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interactiveworldmap

Any ideas how this could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change it to an arrow function.

> Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own this.
> The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout
> the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this
> in the closest non-arrow parent function.

To learn more visit [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-f65639aba256)

```
onRegionClick: () => {
    var selectedCountry = map.getSelectedRegions();
    console.log('selectedCountry: ', selectedCountry);
    this.country = selectedCountry;
    console.log('this.country: ', this.country);
    //this.getCountry();
  },
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interactiveworldmap-inxvde)